# Maclaurin Series - Can't Do this!

Tags: calculus

Find the Maclaurin Series of $\frac{x^2+x}{(1-x)^3}$

The question hints that I should use the derivative of two geometric series, but I am quite lost -- some pointers would be very useful!

Would I perhaps try to find the Macluarin Series for $g(x)=\frac{x}{(1-x)^3}$ and use the fact that $f(x)=x(g(x)+1)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Use
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{(1-x)^{3}}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{d^2}{dx^2} \frac{1}{1-x} = \sum^\infty_{n=2}n(n-1)x^{n-2}.
\end{align}